# How to send jumbo frame in dpdk-pktgen

Tags: networking, network-programming, dpdk, mtu

I'm using **pktgen** in the **DPDK** framework and not able to send packet size more that **1518** byte.
How to increase the maximum packet size and support **Jumbo** frame ?

Comment: Jumbo frames must be enabled on the interface configuration, assuming the interface supports jumbo frames. Remember that jumbo frames are non-standard, and different vendors do them differently, and the same jumbo frame size must be configured on every link between the source and destination, otherwise the jumbo frames will be dropped along the way. This is really a host configuration problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin in DPDK there is no "host configuration": interfaces are directly controlled by DPDK drivers, and get configured using an API. The question is quite legit.

Comment: @RonMaupin In DPDK we use user space drivers, and they need to be configured using an API or an application CLI. We usually can't configure them from the OS level.

Comment: The hardware must be modified at the OS level or it will use the ethernet standard (MTU 1500) and drop jumbo frames (a non-standard configuration that not all hardware supports, and different vendors do it differently). Most ethernet is now done in hardware, and the hardware will drop over-sized frames as giants unless it is told to do otherwise. I see people write about the jumbo frame standard, but there is no such thing. The IEEE maintains the ethernet standard, and insists that the _only_ MTU is 1500; jumbo frames are non-standard, and supported by some hardware in various configurations.

Comment: @RonMaupin No, hardware cannot be modified at the OS level when we use DPDK. Once an ethernet device is bound to DPDK, it disappears and no longer available in the OS. DPDK is a set of user-space ethernet drivers and libraries. DPDK does not use OS drivers, it implements ethernet drivers in user-space. As DPDK applications talk directly to hardware, there is a list of supported NICs: http://core.dpdk.org/supported/ Normally, to enable jumbo frame support in DPDK we pass `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME` flag to `rte_eth_dev_configure()` Hope now it's more clear ;)

Comment: What I am explaining is that in the DPDK manual, it has different ethernet drivers, and the examples of how to configure for jumbo frames is by using the OS CLI to set that on the hardware. It is different for different hardware, and, of course, not all hardware supports jumbo frames because they are non-standard. Different vendors implement it differently, and some not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [this commit](http://git.dpdk.org/apps/pktgen-dpdk/commit/?id=ffc2494bdfcaadb8885b8afcc40be33cf8971372) (made just 10 days after your question) you can pass `-j` to enable jumbo frame support with pktgen.

Comment: Yes.
I communicated to dpdk-pktgen developer's for supporting Jumbo Frame and '-j' flag has been introduced.